# Is there any way to generate a query without subqueries when comparing against multiple columns using the In operator in QueryDSL?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jpa, querydsl

**Summary**

- I want to write a query in QueryDSL that compares using an In clause.

  - No comparison to subqueries.
- Parentheses keep disappearing from first item...
- I want to know if this is the right way to do it, and if not, how to do it properly.

**Details**
The intent of my query is to search for account entities based on multiple (banker, account number) pairs entered from a user. The intention is to retrieve only the entered combinations of "banker,account number" pairs from the table.

**Query intended to run on a real database**

```
select 
    ba.*
from bank_account ba
where (ba.bank_name, ba.account_num ) in 
( /* Variable based on the input list. */
  /* Search for only matches of the following pairs */
    ( 'Hana', '3333-444-555'),
    ( 'Kookmin', '4455-1111-44')
    /* continue ... */
)
```

So, I created the following query with the `Expressions.list()`, completing the left-hand side of the IN clause and putting a literal value instead of a subquery as a parameter of in. (It works fine with a subquery)

```kotlin
fun getBankAccountList( )
jpaQueryFactory.selectFrom(bankAccount)
    .where(
        Expressions.list(
            bankAccount.bank, 
            bankAccount.accountNum, 
        ).`in`(
         /* Input from the user */
            Expressions.list(
                Expressions.constant(BankName.HANA.value),
                Expressions.constant("1234-56-789"),
            ),
            Expressions.list(
                Expressions.constant(BankName.HANA.value),
                Expressions.constant("2345-67-890"),
            ),
            Expressions.list(
                Expressions.constant(BankName.WOORI.value),
                Expressions.constant("3333-33-333"),
            ),
        ) // in()
    ) // where()
.fetch()
```

In the actual generated query, the parentheses in the first term of the two-dimensional array kept disappearing.

**Example generated query** :

```sql
SELECT /*
 columns..
*/
FROM 
    BANK_ACCOUNT B0_
WHERE
(
   B0_.BANK_NAME, B0_.ACCOUNT_NUM
) IN (
    'Hana', '1234-56-789', // Parentheses disappear here...
   ( 'Hana', '1234-56-789'),
   ( 'Woori', '3333-33-333')
)
```

**environment :**

- Language : kotlin (1.5.31)
- Java Version : 11
- queryDSL : 5.0.0
- springBoot : 2.5.6

Is this because I'm not using the IN clause of queryDSL correctly, and if so, what's the right way to do it?